# LOOKUP function in Excel to search values on left and right

Tags: excel, function, lookup

The scenario I'm facing is that in my company we have mixed naming conventions for servers and workstations like:

```
COUNTRYCODE-WORKSTATION1
WORKSTATION10-COUNTRYCODE
COUNTRY-SERVER1
SERVER1-COUNTRYCODE
```

So sometimes I may find names like: BR-WK1 or SRV42-US.

I need to create a PivotTable to extract the amount of events per country so I need to come up with a Lookup function that looks at the first two characters in a cell and if it finds a country code it returns the country code in a country column for that row. If it does not find a country code, it looks at the first two characters on the right, and so on. Country code list will be available in another sheet.

```
IF(LEFT(CELL,CHARNUMBER){COUNTRY LIST}) then (CELLCOUNTRY == {MATCH COUNTY}))
ELSE(RIGHT(CELL,CHARNUMBER){COUNTRY LIST} then (CELLCOUNTRY == {MATCH COUNTRY}))
```

Excel:

```
COUNTRY MACHINE NAME EVENT            DATE        TIME
BR      BR-WK1       Critical type 1  08/01/2015  01:15
US      SRV42-US     Critical type 2  08/01/2015  01:15
BR      WK100-BR     Warning type 8   08/01/2015  01:15
US      US-SRV420    Critical type 1  08/01/2015  01:15
```

Pivot table:

```
Row Labels Count of EVENT          
BR                   2          
US                   2          
Grand Total          4
```

Comment: When you type 'Countries' what would be my input in case the country code list is in another worksheet? If it's in another column in the same worksheet I just need to specify the column and range right?

Comment: Sorry, I did not managed to get it to work. Can you explain me in another way?